# How do you configure Goldengate replication to get source data from different tables

Tags: database-replication, oracle-golden-gate

I have an Oracle database with source data that spans separate tables that need to replicate into one target. The source tables look like this

### EMPLOYEE_DATA_SOURCE

Employee_ID
Employee_Type_A_Status
Employee_Type_B_Status
Employee_Type_C_Status
Employee_Supervisor_ID

### EMPLOYEE_LOCATION_SOURCE

Employee_ID
Employee_Department_ID

### EMPLOYEE_ALT_DATA_SOURCE

Employee_ID
Employee_Supervisor_ID
Employee_Department_ID

The target table has the following columns

### EMPLOYEE_DATA_TARGET

Employee_ID
Employee_Type
Employee_Type_Status
Employee_Supervisor_ID
Employee_Department_ID

The target Employee_Type column is determined by which of the three Employee_Type_X_Status columns has a value in it. In this case, the Emploee_Type will be Type_A, Type_B, or Type_C as only one of the source columns will have a value. The target Employee_Type_Status reflects that value. It could be Active, Inactive, etc. The department and supervisor IDs are pulled from either the location_data or alt_data tables. If the employee is Type_A or Type_B the data should come from location_data. If it is Type_C the data should come from the alt_data table.

In SQL, I would use JOINS to get the correct source data for the target. However, I cannot find good documentation on how one would do this with Goldengate parameter files. Is it possible to define these relationships so that the process maps the correct source data to the appropriate target column?